# react-native flatList renders blank screen

Tags: react-native-flatlist

I'm really new to react-native.
I'm trying to do a flatList.
At first it worked but then I added the bottom tab bar and then it didn't work anymore.
I tried to go back and delete the bottom tab bar but I always have an error.
The Last one was "can't find data". And now without changing anything, I just have a blank screen.

My code :

```
// Helpers/membersData.js

export default data = [
{
   id:1,
   name: "Name",
   firstname: "Firstname",
   address: "some address",
   zipcode : 75000,
   city: "city",
   phone: "",
   email: "name.e@gmail.com"
},
{
    id:2,
    name: "Othername",
    firstname: "Otherfirstname",
    address: "Other address",
    zipcode : 75000,
    city: "City",
    phone: "0600000000",
    email: "name.first@gmail.com"
}

]
```

The flatList :

```
// Components/Members.js

  import members from '../Helpers/membersData';
  import React from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';
  import MemberDetails from './MemberDetails';


 class Members extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.main_container}>
            <FlatList
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                data={members}
                renderItem={({item}) => <MemberDetails member={item}/>}
            />

        </View>
     )
    }
   }

  const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   main_container: {
    marginTop: 25,
    marginLeft: 10
   }
  })

  export default Members
```

The list details
    // Components/MemberDetails.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'

class MemberDetails extends React.Component {
render() {
const member = this.props.member
return (
  <View style={styles.main_container}>

    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <Text>{member.name}</Text>
      <Text style={{marginLeft:10}}>{member.firstname}</Text>
    </View>

    <View >
      <Text >{member.address}</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
      <Text >{member.zipcode}</Text>
      <Text  style={{marginLeft:10}}>{member.city}</Text>
    </View>

      <Text>{member.phone}</Text>
      <Text  style={{marginLeft:10}}>{member.email}</Text>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
main_container: {
height: 190,
flexDirection: 'column',
alignItems: 'center'
  },
})


export default MemberDetails
```

The App.js

```
//import Members from './Components/Members'

import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import Members from './Components/Members'
import Homepage from './Components/Homepage'
import SubscriptionsList from './Components/SubscriptionsList'


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
 return (
   <NavigationContainer>
     <Tab.Navigator>
       <Tab.Screen name="Accueil" component={Homepage} />
       <Tab.Screen name="Membres" component={Members} />
       <Tab.Screen name="Abonnements" component={SubscriptionsList} />
     </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
 );
 }
```

I don't know what I did wrong.
I'd really appreciate some help.
Thanks !

Comment: you are  importing members from membersData while you are exporting the array as data from membersData file. Maybe thats the problem you are giving wrong data to the flatlist

Answer (score 0):

use

```
export default [
{
   id:1,
   name: "Name",
   firstname: "Firstname",
   address: "some address",
   zipcode : 75000,
   city: "city",
   phone: "",
   email: "name.e@gmail.com"
},
{
    id:2,
    name: "Othername",
    firstname: "Otherfirstname",
    address: "Other address",
    zipcode : 75000,
    city: "City",
    phone: "0600000000",
    email: "name.first@gmail.com"
}

]
```